# How does the cross-chain protocol handle rollback cases?

Tags: bridge, cross-chain

When bridging assets from a source chain to a destination chain using a cross chain protocol (e.g. Circle's CCTP, li.fi's cross swap), what happens if I successfully transferFrom() and burn() (or lock()) on the source chain but fail to mint() or transfer() on the destination chain? Can I get back the burned or locked assets on the source chain?

For example, let's say you're bridging USDC on ethereum to USDC on polygon using CCTP.
Alice sends 1000$ of USDC from ethereum to CCTP and it is successfully burned (CCTP is a burn&mint pattern), but when polygon fails to mint it back to alice (due to insufficient gas, chain failure, etc.), how does alice get her USDC back? Is there a way to roll back from the source chain, ethereum?